# Use of undeclared identifier 'CCJumpBy'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

This is my code

```
#import "Gameplay.h"
#import <CCActionInterval.h>

@implementation Gameplay {
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    // tell this scene to accept touches
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
 - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self jumpRunner];
}


-(void)jumpRunner {
    CCNode *spaceship = [CCBReader load:@"Runner"];

    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(100, 0)
                                height:50 jumps:1];
    [spaceship runAction:jump];
}

@end
```

It's telling me

`Use of undeclared identifier 'CCJumpBy'`

How do I fix this to make it work? I don't know what to do.
    Thanx in advance

Comment: If you changed your code based on responses, can you change your question code to show what you have updated?

Answer (score 2):

Import cocos2d and you should resolve the error

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to `#import` the `CCJumpBy` class's header file.

Also I notice that you're `#import`ing a .m file, which generally you don't do. You probably want to change your import of `CCActionInterval` to be the .h file, not the .m file.

Comment: How do i import the CCJumpBy class?

Answer (score 0):

CCJumpBy is defined in `CCActionInterval.h`.

Change your import to

```
#import <CCActionInterval.h>
```

And you should resolve this error.